# What happened to the "notar" (left-over) of the 1st Pesach lamb?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, time, korban, yetziat-mitzrayim, bo

Exodus 12:8:

וְאָכְל֥וּ אֶת־הַבָּשָׂ֖ר בַּלַּ֣יְלָה הַזֶּ֑ה

> And they shall eat the flesh in that night.

Exodus 12:10:

וְלֹא־תוֹתִ֥ירוּ מִמֶּ֖נּוּ עַד־בֹּ֑קֶר וְהַנֹּתָ֥ר מִמֶּ֛נּוּ עַד־בֹּ֖קֶר בָּאֵ֥שׁ תִּשְׂרֹֽפוּ׃

> And ye shall let nothing of it remain until the morning; but that
>   which remaineth of it until the morning ye shall burn with fire.

*B'nai Yisra'el* left Egypt early in the morning, they were told to leave in a hurry, and the Torah says that they were chased out and had to leave so quickly that they didn't prepare food nor did they have time to let the dough rise.

What happened to the left over Pesach lamb? Was there absolutely no left over with anyone at all? If there was, when did they have time to burn it?

Comment: Crucial to your question is the claimed fact that the Jews left early in the morning. (Without that, you really have no question.) Can you source that claim?

Comment: @msh210 - I'm not assuming either side, necessarily. Contrarily, if there is a source for what you claim, that makes a good answer. I assume that even if they left later in the morning, all the other hurried activities might have precluded their having the time to burn it. Or, my other possibility - everyone ate everything and there was no left over.

Comment: Note that you cannot burn leftover Kodshim on Yom Tov so any extra meat would have been burned on the morning of 16 Nissan (that is in reference to a regular pesach; your year is before Mattan Torah so perhaps it's different)